# How to disable the click/touch events for parent and child recyclerview(nested recyclerview) but scrolling needs to work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have tried with this code.

```
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
                }
            });
```

Using this disabling the touch event is working fine. But scrolling not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe the RecyclerView will not have any click/touch enabled, so you don't really need to do anything to get the behavior you want. Adding a `addOnItemTouchListener` this way will definitely block the scrolling behavior if you don't fully implement the `onTouchEvent` which seems unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Hi @pratik K,  I have tried this override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {
                    if(e.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
                        // allow Parent RecyclerView to intercept touch events.
                        recyclerview!!.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false) }  Still facing the scrolling issue.